# Why size of Jtext area is Changing on selecting other componenets on Jframe form

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextarea

I am having three radio buttons **(rd_7inch, rd_9inch, and rd_10inch)** on selection i am 
changing size of text box

**SetSize()**

```
public  void setsize()
{
    if(rd_7inch.isSelected())
    {   jScrollPane2.setSize(300, 300);
        txt_sysnp.setSize(220,250);
        System.out.println("******** 7inch : "+rd_7inch.isSelected());
    }else if(rd_9inch.isSelected())
    {   jScrollPane2.setSize(300, 350);
        txt_sysnp.setSize(300,350);
        System.out.println("******** 9inch : "+rd_9inch.isSelected());

    }else 
    {   jScrollPane2.setSize(400,400);
        txt_sysnp.setSize(400,400);
        System.out.println("******** 10inch : "+rd_10inch.isSelected());
    }
}

 private void Cmb_CategoryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        try {
            String catname = Cmb_Category.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int catindex = Cmb_Category.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println(catname);
            System.out.println(catindex);
            String catpos = Category_list_pages.get(catindex);
            System.out.println(catpos);
            int catpages = Integer.parseInt(catpos);

            for (int i = 1; i <= catpages; i++) {
                Cmb_pageno.addItem("page" + i);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        setsize();
    }
```

I am having **1 Jcombo box** and **2 buttons** on click of both components size of Jtext area changes which should be constant for particular resulutions.

Comment: `Cmb_CategoryActionPerformed`is the combobox ?? if yes , why you call `setsize` method on it ?

Comment: I would suggest you to simply change `Rows/Columns` for the `JTextArea`, instead of changing the size explicitly. Let `Layout Manager` do that task for you, simply call `revalidate()/repaint()` on the parent container containing the `JTextArea` after changing `Rows/Columns`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the final `else` statement , you didn't specify else what (I mean you need to specify the else statement with `rd_10inch` only ), so you do it with the other component

```
else if (rd_10inch.isSelected())/////////////////here i specify the else on the third button only 
    {   jScrollPane2.setSize(400,400);
        txt_sysnp.setSize(400,400);
        System.out.println("******** 10inch : "+rd_10inch.isSelected());
    }
```

Comment: and where you call `setsize` method?